# A basic confusion regarding a question in measure theory

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I have this problem in my measure theory book:

$E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ is a measurable set with $0<\lambda(E)<\infty$. Suppose ther is a sequence of measurable sets $A_n \subseteq E$ with $\lambda(A_n) \rightarrow \lambda(E)$, show that there exists a subsequence of sets $\{A_{n_k}\}$ such that $\lambda(\cap A_{n_k}) >0$.

But this problem seems trivial to me as even a much stronger result can be proved. Simply,
$$\lambda(\cap A_{n_k}) = \lim \lambda(A_{n_k}) = \lim \lambda(A_n) \rightarrow \lambda(E) >0$$

This $\lambda(\cap A_{n_k}) > 0$ for *all* subsequences $A_{n_k}$.

Please comment.

Comment: What does $\lambda(\cap A_{n_k}) \rightarrow \lambda(A_{n_k})$ mean?

Comment: Did you copy the problem down correctly?

Comment: I guess you want that the **intersection** of all sets in the subsequence has positive measure?!

Comment: The problem was incorrect. I corrected it. Yes I want the intersection to have positive measure

Comment: The first equality in your argument can fail in general.